# Laravel 4 - Input::all() is not containing values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Input:all is not showing the post data. Any clue why? I have already tried Input:all before and I haven't experienced this.

```
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r(Input::all());
    exit;

  Array
(
    [_token] => Sr4MSYL2ovDWMtU3o2Ms6YULFcxsuFYtAasS3Vqu
    [username] => name
    [password] => password
)
Array
(
)
```

This is my login view. I don't think that this has anything to do with the issue though.

```
 @extends("layout")
    @section("content")
      {{ Form::open() }}
        {{ $errors->first("password") }}<br />
        {{ Form::label("username", "Username") }}
        {{ Form::text("username", Input::old("username")) }}
        {{ Form::label("password", "Password") }}
        {{ Form::password("password") }}
        {{ Form::submit("login") }}
      {{ Form::close() }}
    @stop
```

Comment: When you say, you have tried it before, does that mean it works for other routes/controllers/methods in the same app, just not this specific case?

Comment: Maybe you move the login controller to another namespace? Have you tried `\Input::all()`?